# If $f(x), g(x)$ polynomials and assume $g(n)\neq0$ for each $n\in N$, then radius of convergence of $\sum \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}r^n$ is $R=1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I got the following question from a test:

If $f(x), g(x)$ polynomials. assume $g(n)\neq0$ for each $n\in N$, then radius of convergence of $\sum \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}r^n$ is $R=1$?

I think that it is true. because I think that by using Cauchy–Hadamard theorem we will get radius of 1.

My problem is that I don't really know to value the the limit for any polynomials.

Comment: Well, if $f \equiv 0$ then clearly the radius is $\infty$...

Comment: Ratio test is easier to use.

Comment: @Mark, well I hadn't thought about that. without f(x)=0, does it true?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Root test and

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac {f (n+1)}{f (n)}=1$$

if $$f (x)=a_mx^m+...+a_0 $$

Comment: well, after showing it, that it is very simple to use 
$$R^{-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\lvert$$
I'm wrong?

Comment: @Y.ofir no. you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

A polynomial can have only a finite set of roots, and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{h(n)}{n^{{\rm deg}\,h}} $ is the leading coefficient of $h$.